# Как правильно: пересогласование или пересогласовывание?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, существительные

Как правильно написать: *документ требует **пересогласовывания*** или *документ требует **пересогласования***?

Answer (score 1):

Существуют оба слова.

В словарях есть упоминание о пересогласовывании: [https://all_words.academic.ru/61433/пересогласовывание](https://all_words.academic.ru/61433/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Пересогласование - название/факт самого действия.

Пересогласовывание - процесс совершения этого действия:

`В данный момент они занимаются пересогласовыванием.`

Документ явно требует факта совершения действия, а не конкретно самого процесса. И для юриспруденции это актуально.

Вывод: лучше пересогласование.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97787/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-----).

Answer (score 0):

По принципу меньшего из зол - **пересогласования**.
Слово явно неуклюжее, но оно по крайней мере фиксируется словарями. 
А вот "пересогласовавание" - это вообще что-то из потустороннего мира.

А нельзя написать как-то более просто? *Повторного согласования, нового согласования*?

Comment: У вас `по крайней мере` вводное. Не вводное в значении «не меньше чем», «самое меньшее», «минимум»: по крайней мере (чего?) уверенности или после какое-то число. Источник: new.gramota. "Пересогласовавание"??? Это естественно, что вы не нашли его в словарях.

Comment: Более того, в словарях упоминается также `пересогласовыванье`. Вот тут уже без понятия, чем это слово отличается от тех двух.

Comment: @oleedd *пересогласовыванье* - что за словарь у вас?

Comment: Большой толковый словарь русского языка © С.А. Кузнецов, 2010. Там же и пример есть. Вообще не представляю этого слова (разницы), в отличие от двух других. Интересно ваше мнение...

Comment: По аналогии с `избиранье` (где тоже есть 3 варианта) можно предположить, что это просто устаревшая форма.

Comment: @oleedd ваши комментарии становятся излишне назойливыми. Все содерджательное, что можно из них я уже выжал. Вы некритично пользуетесь словарем Кузнецова - этого уже достаточно, чтобы составить мнение.

Comment: Ладно-ладно. Запятую после `можно` пропустили. Но сама по себе структура этого предложения вообще не правильная. Этого тоже уже достаточно, чтобы составить мнение.